# Get object URL from FileEntry (or equivalent)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, blob

I am currently loading dropped files by doing:

```
var files = e.dataTransfer.items;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i]; //typeof is 'DataTransferItem'
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
```

This gets me the object url, which I can then put into a music player. However, when iterating over an inputted folder:

```
var reader = entry.createReader();
reader.readEntries(function (res) {
    res.forEach(function (entry) {
        console.log('The entry:', entry);
        console.log('The url:', JSON.stringify(entry.toURL()));
    });
});
```

I get files of type `FileEntry`. According to [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-filesystemurls) I shall be able to do `file.toURL()` and use that instead of an object url. This does return me an empty string. [this seems to be there for a reason](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=148788), but I have no idea how to fix this. I see something about a blob URL but I have no idea how that would work.
[***Example***](http://jsfiddle.net/cLS5j/13/)
Try to drag files and folders to the output screen and see it yourself

Comment: the blob url is the same as window.URL's urls.

Comment: @dandavis But how would I get that URL?

Comment: It's complicated. you can see a (sloppy) routine i used starting on about line 1960 on http://danml.com/dev/devsite.js, but it's confusing enough to me looking back on it that i'm not sure how instructive it will be, but i know it works to allow dropping folders into http://danml.com/dev/...

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. On the `FileEntry` I do .file(function(file){}) where file is just a normal `typeof File` where I can create an object URL from. I found this on line 1979 of your file :)

Comment: @dandavis / MarijnS95, either of you should probably post the solution as an answer to this question, so others who have the same problem will find the answer more easily.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I am currently busy writing an elaborated answer to this, to provide others a good base to start from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How I fixed it:

from an entry with typeof `FileEntry`, we can just do `.file(callback)`, where the first parameter in the callback is of type `File`, which we can then just create an objectURL from:

```
var reader = entry.createReader();
reader.readEntries(function (res) {
    res.forEach(function (entry) {
        entry.file(function(file){ //this does the trick
            var obj = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }
    });
});
```

Many thanks to dandavis who provided me his javascript code and the approximate line so I could go look for it myself ;)